# How can I reduce validation strictness for Maven resolution in Shrinkwrap?

Tags: maven, validation, jboss, pom.xml, shrinkwrap

I am using JBoss Shrinkwrap 3.1.4 to resolve dependencies for given Maven coordinates. To achieve this, the following code is doing a fine job in most cases:

> var artifacts = Maven.configureResolver() 
> .withClassPathResolution(false) 
> .loadPomFromFile(f) 
> .importCompileAndRuntimeDependencies() 
> .resolve() 
> .withTransitivity() 
> .asResolvedArtifact();

However, in some cases Shrinkwrap is not able to build the POM model and identifies validation problems in the POM file. For example, for javax.mail:mail:1.4.3, I get the following error message:

> org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.InvalidConfigurationFileException: Found 4 problems while building POM model from /root/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.pom 
> 1/ [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ javax.mail:mail:1.4.3, /root/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.pom 
> 2/ [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ javax.mail:mail:1.4.3, /root/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.pom
> 3/ [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin is missing. @ javax.mail:mail:1.4.3, /root/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.pom 
> 4/ [ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is 'RELEASE'. @ javax.mail:mail:1.4.3, /root/.m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.pom

I am only interested in the dependencies... these problems in the build section (like error 4) are irrelevant for me. I am wondering, if it is somehow possible to reduce validation strictness when processing the POM files (or disable it altogether), but I could not find anything in the APIs.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

best
Sebastian

Comment: Can you give more details in particular about your pom file because your pom configuration is simply wrong because your code implies to resolve things which means your pom file must be correct and working apart from your own interest......apart from that things like javax.mail:mail:1.4.3 are more than 10 years old...Which

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding my setup, I am not analyzing my own poms, but poms taken from Maven Central on a large scale. In the concrete case, I am trying to resolve the dependencies for said `mail-1.4.3` (i.e., I download the pom and then invoke the above code)... when I do this, Shrinkwrap fails with the warning/errors that I posted above. My own pom has nothing to do with that. I would like to get Shrinkwrap to ignore all validation errors that are unrelated to dependency resolution.

Comment: The problem in the pom you are analysing is this: `build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.codehaus.mojo:findbugs-maven-plugin must be a valid version but is 'RELEASE` which is simply wrong...

Comment: I understand WHY the errors appear, but I don't need this part of the pom, so the whole `build` block could be ignored... Which is why I am asking about relaxation of pom validation.

Comment: The build block can not be ignored because it will not work otherwise... pom relaxation ? Have you checked the framework if it is able to do ? I would recommend to fix the issues in your pom file it's easier...

Comment: I am ONLY interested in resolving dependencies, so the dependencies and dependencyManagement blocks are the only relevant information in the pom for me. Most importantly, I do not want to build the project as these are not "my" poms... but nevermind, we are running in circles, I don't think you get what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the building part of the pom?

Comment: I say it again, I have no control over the pom, I consume them directly from Maven central. (I would like to build a large DB with dependent/dependency information).

Comment: As I wrote before check the framework if it supports it otherwise there is no other choice

Comment: Considering that my question is literally if someone knows whether this is supported by the framework, I do not find this answer particularly helpful ;)